# DSolve not working on vector equation

Tags: differential-equations

Ok, so I'm trying to solve a differential equation of motion, and mathematica doesn't do anything to my input. It just leaves it unevaluated.  I know that the system is physically solvable with not too much difficulty, but I can't get mathematica to do it. My guess is that it has something to do with the vectors?

Anyway, below is the textform of the code, and I attached an image as well.[image: Differential equation image form]

```
DSolve[{Overscript[a, \[RightVector]][t]==(-m {0,0,\[CapitalOmega]z}\[Cross]({0,0,\[CapitalOmega]z}\[Cross]Overscript[r, \[RightVector]][t])-2 m {0,0,\[CapitalOmega]z}\[Cross]Overscript[v, \[RightVector]][t])/m,Overscript[a, \[RightVector]][t]==(Overscript[r, \[RightVector]]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t],Overscript[v, \[RightVector]][t]==(Overscript[r, \[RightVector]]^\[Prime])[t],Overscript[r, \[RightVector]][0]=={5,5,5},(Overscript[r, \[RightVector]]^\[Prime])[0]=={5,5,5}},{Overscript[a, \[RightVector]],Overscript[v, \[RightVector]],Overscript[r, \[RightVector]]},t]
```

Comment: You might want to look at the examples in the DSolve help, and then remove all the Overscript functions (which have no purpose).

Answer (score 2):

`m` seems like it appears both in numerator and denominator on the RHS, drop those.

`Overscript[a, \[RightVector]]` and `Overscript[v, \[RightVector]]` can be calculated directly from `Overscript[r, \[RightVector]]`, replace those with appropriate formulations of `r`, find `r` and calculate `a` and `v` afterwards.

I've had difficulties in the past trying to get Mathematica to deal with "abstract" vectors, turn `Overscript[r, \[RightVector]]` into a concrete vector.

```
r[t]={x[t],y[t],z[t]};
r[t]/.DSolve[{D[r[t],{t,2}]==(-1*{0,0,Ωz}\[Cross]({0,0,Ωz}\[Cross]r[t])-
  2*{0,0,Ωz}\[Cross]D[r[t],t]),
  {x[0],y[0],z[0]}=={5,5,5},{x'[0],y'[0],z'[0]}=={5,5,5}},r[t],t]//Simplify
```

instantly returns

```
{{((-5/2-(5*I)/2)*(-1 + t*(-1 - I*Ωz) + E^((2*I)*t*Ωz)*(I + t*(I + Ωz))))/E^(I*t*Ωz),
  ((5/2 + (5*I)/2)*(-I + t*(-I + Ωz) + E^((2*I)*t*Ωz)*(1 + t - I*t*Ωz)))/E^(I*t*Ωz),
  5*(1 + t)}}
```

Astonishingly, substituting the solution into the original equation yields `True`!

If I've made any mistakes in this then please point them out. I will be the least surprised of anyone if I've made several terrible mistakes in this.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work with abstract vectors?

Comment: @IonSme  Not to my knowledge.